# função para contar quantidade de DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar uma função para verificar a quantidade de DIVs na tela e inserir uma class dentro da quarta por exemplo. Essas DIVs são criadas dinamicamente.

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div').length);` Vai contar o total de divs que você tem no DOM. Sua dúvida está um pouco confusa, por exemplo você vai inserir sempre na 4 div que encontrar no documento, ou seja é fixo? Existe algum botão ou evento que vai acionar a inserção da classe?

Comment: Veja funcionado [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyaq46n6/2/)

Comment: "Na tela" você diz na página inteira ou apenas na parte visível da página?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra selecionar **TODAS** as `divs` você pode simplesmente usar o seletor com:

```
var divs = $('div'); // Armazena um `NodeList` com todos os elementos
```

Quantidade:

```
var qtd = divs.length; // Numero inteiro da quantidade de divs
```

Para alterar a `div` desejada você pode usar a função `addClass` ou `css` do `jquery`, lembre-se que a contagem das `divs` se inicia do 0 então se você quiser trocar por exemplo a cor da fonte da quarta  `div` ficaria assim:

```
$(divs[3]).addClass('red');
```

```js
var divs = $('div');
var length = divs.length;

$(divs[3]).addClass('red');
// Ou
$(divs[3]).css({
  color: 'red'
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
```

Para alterar as `divs` com repetição (de 4 em 4) você pode utilizar o seletor `css` `nth-child(xn+x)`, que funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
$('div:nth-child(4n+0)').css({
    color: 'red'
});
```

Explicação:

`nth-child` seleciona o numero da `div` que você quer por exemplo `:nth-child(1)`, selecione o primeiro elemento e assim por diante, se você utilizar como no exemplo acima ele usara a seguinte lógica:

`:nth-child(4n...` pule de 4 em 4.

`...+0)` começando do 0

Você pode testar alterando os numeros:
`:nth-child(2n+1)` "Pule de 2 em 2 começando do primeiro"

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Preciso complicar um pouco, como eu posso fazer para essa função com as DIVs e de 4 em 4 ela acrescente um class?

Comment: @carlosgiovanicasilo sugiro que faça isso com `css` puro, seria mais facil, mas vou adicionar a na resposta.

Comment: Caleu mesmo pela ajuda, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Pelo problema que você apresentou, não é necessário o uso de Javascript. O incremento na contagem de elementos pode ser feito através da propriedade [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) e a soma dos elementos pode ser feito com a função [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

Obter o quarto elemento, pode ser feito com as pseudo classes [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) ou [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

```css
/* Todo elemento <div> irá incrementar o contador "divnumber". */
div {
  counter-increment: divnumber
}

/* "counter" irá pegar o valor de "divnumber". */
span::after {
  content: 'Existem ' counter(divnumber) ' divs.'
}

/* ntd-child irá pegar o quarto elemento <div>. */
div:nth-child(4) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
<div>div4</div>
<div>div5</div>


<br><br>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajustei o código para contar as divs e só preencher caso tenha acima de 3.
Pego todas as divs que contém a classe 'd' para contagem e modificação.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      if(jQuery('.d').length > 3){
        jQuery(jQuery('.d')[3]).addClass('red');
      } else{
        alert('A quantidade de divs na tela é inferior a 4');
      }
    })
```

```css
.red{
          background: red;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          float:left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

Comment: Sua função não está verificando a quantidade de divs existentes. Dá para reverter o negativo.

Comment: @MagicHat alteração feita.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $('div').each(function(i, value)
                    {
                        if(i ==3)
                        {
                            $(value).addClass('teste');
                        }
                    });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Como a pergunta não especificou o uso de **JQuery**, acho que cabe uma solução com Javascript Vanilla:

```
// Obter a quantidade de divs
var quantidadeDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;

// Obter array com todas as divs da página
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

// Adicionando a classe vermelho na quarta div
divs[3].classList.add('vermelho');
```